# How to get Youtube Data API data with Node

Tags: json, node.js, api, youtube, request

I am trying to get a response from the Youtube Data API using the Node request module. I can get the response I want using JQuery, but cannot get any data I can understand with node.

```
var request=require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
var ACCESS_TOKEN='*******************';

request.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=ambient&type=video&key='+ACCESS_TOKEN,function(err,header,body){
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(body);
})
```

When I console log the body, it's of type 'buffer' (not familiar with buffers)

How to I get the json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `.defaults({ encoding: null })` you should get the json data.

```
var request = require('request');
var ACCESS_TOKEN = '*******************';

request.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=ambient&type=video&key=' + ACCESS_TOKEN, function(err, header, body) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(body);
});
```

By setting the encoding to `null` you are telling it to return it as a `Buffer`.

> encoding - Encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. **If null, the body is returned as a Buffer**. Anything else (including the default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). (Note: if you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null.)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#request-options-callback

Comment: I tried that before but must have had some other mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.88.2 request package has been deprecated: As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully deprecated. No new changes are expected land. In fact, none have landed for some time.

For more information about why request is deprecated and possible alternatives refer to [request npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

I change to [axios npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and it's working fine with NodeJS on server-side.
Example:

```
axios.get('https://www.some.url').then(response => {
    console.log('> response:', response);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Or there are some different ways to make HTTP Requests in Node.js from [this link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html)